# AngularJS - Bind scope change from outside directive - Codepen included

Tags: angularjs

**Question Background:**

I'm using NoUiSlider to provide a Range slide for my AngularJS app.

**The Issue:**

The NoUiSlider is ound to a div that updates the value of that div by its id (for both max and min values) as expected.

I want to allow the changed values to be bound to an upper and lower `$scope` variable i.e `$scope.max` and `$scope.min`

**Codepen:**

The following Codepen gives an example of what I would like to implement.

http://codepen.io/daveharris/pen/xVNVLR

As can be seen I have provided an `ng-model` on the div's showing the Min and Max values to a corresponding `$scope.max` and `$scope.min`.

How can I provide a way of updating the `$scope.min` and `$scope.max` values when i change the div value of min and max?

Comment: This is why mixing Angular and jQuery is such a PITA. You'll probably have to wrap the jQuery stuff in a directive and use it that way. You should be able to find some helpful questions to get you started and then you can ask a more specific question if you still can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If the slider is only for jQuery you are going to have to re-write the whole thing into a directive for Angular (great learning experience), but why? F... that noise! Just use a Slider that is already an Angular directive:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider